# Twelve-Factor App philosophy on Logs using Laravel

Tags: php, cloud, saas

Quoting from [The Twelve-Factor App](http://12factor.net/logs), it states that on local development logs are to be printed to `stdout` and not written to log files:

> A twelve-factor app never concerns itself with routing or storage of its output stream. It should not attempt to write to or manage logfiles. Instead, each running process writes its event stream, unbuffered, to stdout. During local development, the developer will view this stream in the foreground of their terminal to observe the app’s behavior.

Moreover, on production:

> In staging or production deploys, each process’ stream will be captured by the execution environment, collated together with all other streams from the app, and routed to one or more final destinations for viewing and long-term archival.

How would a PHP application (specifically a Laravel application) would write logs to `stdout` so that I can view from the terminal in local dev? Also, I didn't understand the production way, can I get some directions?

Comment: I wonder if the purpose of this suggestion is so applications don't lock themselves too much to choices that are environment dependent, and may need to change dynamically e.g. in live. Thus, if you make logging configurable per environment, and you have ways to turn on/off extra logging streams without extra coding, that is good (e.g. how to capture bug behaviour in live without a fresh deployment?). Monolog supports log streams.